# How to set X-Frame Options to ALLOW-FROM https://example.com and SAMEORIGIN on server

Tags: iframe, webserver, x-frame-options

I have a requirement to set the X-Frame options on the **server level** to either:

> - X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> - X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/

Understand that X-Frame Options are mutually exclusive. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

However, my application requires framing in **https://example.com** and also from its **SAMEORIGIN**.

Please advise if there is a way around this while retainining my application's requirement to having allow framing on the **same origin**  and be framed on **1 external site**.

Or is this impossible?

Comment: any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In addition to only supporting one instance of the header, `X-Frame-Options` does not support any more than just one site, `SAMEORIGIN` or not.

You'll have to use `Content-Security-Policy` and `frame-ancestors`, which does support multiple origins, like so:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com
```

A couple notes to bear in mind:

- [`frame-ancestors` obsoletes `X-Frame-Options`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options) - meaning that if `frame-ancestors` is present and the browser supports it, it will override the behaviour of `X-Frame-Options`.
- Internet Explorer does not support the `frame-ancestors` directive, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors#Browser_compatibility). This means they will fall back to `X-Frame-Options`. If you need to support multiple origins in IE, [see this answer on SO with a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257574/4220785).

Comment: This answer is the right one and should be accepted (and upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and i handled in global.asax. i checked from where the request is coming and based on that i changed the header value to either sameorigin or allow-from. hope that helps.