# X-Frame-Options: ALLOW FROM URI Will Not Display iFrame

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, x-frame-options

I have been trying to allow another website to display an iFRAME of a pdf from our website. When they try to iFRAME it is blank and the error is:

**Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://longurl.pdf does not permit cross-origin framing.**

I attribute this error to our site as inspecting the headers shows me:

**X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**

It is a wordrpess/Genesis site so I added in my functions.php

```
add_action('send_headers', 'xframe_options');
function xframe_options(){
    header("X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://amdsb-on.safeschools.com/");
}
```

I am still getting the blank page and the exact same error on the https://amdsb-on.safeschools.com/ site when trying to display the iFRAME

When I inspect my site now I see:

**X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://amdsb-on.safeschools.com/, SAMEORIGIN**

All my research tells me this is what you should do to allow a specific site to iFRAME yours. is it because it is a pdf? Is it because one site has SSL and one doesn't?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` can’t contain multiple directives; so in your case, you can only do either `ALLOW-FROM` or `SAMEORIGIN`. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335585/441757: *In addition to only supporting one instance of the header, `X-Frame-Options` does not support any more than just one site, `SAMEORIGIN` or not. You'll have to use `Content-Security-Policy` and `frame-ancestors`, which does support multiple origins.* So for the specific case described in this question here, you’d want to do: `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://amdsb-on.safeschools.com/`