# Allow multiple URLs for X-Frame-Options ALLOW FROM for frame with inner frame

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, frame, x-frame-options

I have a requirement to secure a site by restricting permissible URIs for framing. There are others posted here on the same subject such as [Content-Security-Policy (CSP) workaround for internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771399/content-security-policy-csp-workaround-for-internet-explorer/42257574#42257574) (and contains Microsoft's recommended approach which can be found at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/).

I need to utilize `X-Frame-Options` for legacy browsers and `Internet Explorer`. As most are aware, X-Frame-Options only accepts one URL. I took the Microsoft approach to heart to tackle this problem, but I have run into an obstacle.

The site that is framed is an ASP.NET vendor application. I don't have much control over it, beyond maybe modifying ASPX, JavaScript, or config files, as needed. It's a CMS application so there could be countless pages.

Let's say the URL for the framed site is `vendorapp.example.com`. The parent site it's embedded in is `parent.example.com`. With Microsoft's approach of passing the origin URL to the querystring and then settings X-Frame-Options ALLOW FROM, it can work. The problem is the vendor application also uses frames. The frame is always itself. To further complicate things, there are instances where vendorapp.example.com is not framed and I need to account for both situations, where it's embedded in parent.example.com and when it's not. Here's what it looks like from the perspective of parent.example.com:

```
// parent.example.com
// Calls vendor application in frame
<frame src="http://vendorapp.example.com/?param1=1&param2=2" />
```

And here is the perspective from within the vendor application:

```
// vendorapp.example.com

// May or may not have its own inner frame. Points to itself.
<frame = src="http://vendorapp.example.com/articleid=14&otherparam=otherparam" />
```

From the perspective of parent.example.com, at best, I have one inner frame. At worst, I have two inner frames.

Since this is a vendor application, my method to attack this has been using `IIS` `URL Rewrite` on the vendorapp.example.com server. I pass a parameter in the querystring that corresponds to parent.example.com. URL Rewrite reads this parameter and sets X-Frame-Options in an `Outbound Rule`. One problem with URL Rewrite is it has to be set for each request. It's not like I can set X-Frame-Options one time and forget about it. The other issue is this will break if the vendor application has its own frame and I can't update the frame to add a querystring parameter. That's not an option. I'm not quite sure how to deal with this problem, other than Internet Explorer users will have to open vendorapp.example.com in its own window and will be unable to view it in a frame.

I don't have to use URL Rewrite to solve this. I'm open to any solution here. But please understand, again, it's a vendor application. I do not have the option of modifying their compiled code and this is not something I can approach the vendor with and ask them to resolve. This is a "you're on your own" type of problem.